# How does Cantor's diagonal argument actually prove that the set of real numbers is larger than that of natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I have looked into Cantor's diagonal argument, but I am not entirely convinced. Instead of starting with 1 for the natural numbers and working our way up, we could instead try and pair random, infinitely long natural numbers with irrational real numbers, like follows:

- `97249871263434289...   0.12834798234890899...`
- `29347192834769812...   0.23489712349789878...`
- `42987412938478321...   0.23487912836784798...`
- `43921649873612384...   0.58792834796781823...`
- `49238749213847921...   0.58971238456497213...`
- `98123489712348790...   0.58291739429587199...`
- `45678294218374691...   0.09123498915832837...`
- `69217346876217384...   0.23897123484839759...`
- `52189347981283490...   0.34823948750038273...`
- `.`
- `.`
- `.`

Couldn't we just as easily apply the diagonal argument to the natural numbers, and therefore generate a new natural number after completely exhausting our list? Here's another way to look at it:

- `97249871263434289...   0.0`
- `29347192834769812...   0.1`
- `42987412938478321...   0.2`
- `43921649873612384...   0.3`
- `.`
- `.`
- `.`
- `49238749213847921...   0.8`
- `98123489712348790...   0.9`
- `45678294218374691...   0.10`
- `69217346876217384...   0.11`
- `52189347981283490...   0.12`
- `.`
- `.`
- `.`

If we accept Cantor's diagonal argument, doesn't the second argument now prove that there are more natural numbers than real numbers between 0 and 1? If you imagine this infinite list of real numbers, which in fact does include all numbers between 0 and 1 (or else the set [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...] wouldn't contain all the natural numbers), it seems like the only distinction between the two sets are the inclusion of a preceding "0." for the real numbers. Does that magically make the set larger?

Comment: What is an “infinitely long natural number”?

Comment: List all natural numbers : $0,1,2,\ldots$. May you please, show in what way you want to "diagonalize" it in order to produce a number not in the list ?

Comment: There is probably a slew of other duplicates that will illuminate you on the workings and failings of the diagonal argument.

Answer (score 3):

There are no "infinitely long natural numbers". Natural numbers have a finite decimal expansion.

Indeed, if you are looking at "infinite decimal expansions", i.e. possibly infinite strings of the digits 0 to 9, this set is uncountably infinite.

Comment: ...and if you put a decimal point in front of each of them, you get all the (real) numbers between $0$ and $1$, which is the starting point for the Cantor diagonal argument.